# (Spring-Boot/CXF/JAXRS) @GET responds correctly with 200, @POST responds with 404 despite identical configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf

**ISSUE**

The issue is that my endpoints with @GET annotation work just fine and results in a 200. @POST results in a 404. They are configured almost identically. Console does not report any errors.

**Background**

I am setting up a controller to contain a series of GETs and POSTs.
I am using SpringBoot/Tomcat.
The specific library is cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs (version: 3.3.3)

I followed this guide for setup:
https://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html

As I understand, the spring boot starter handles the servlet setup, so I don't have that to share.

Server and service bean initialization looks like this:

```
    @Autowired
    private List<? extends BaseController> controllers;

    @Bean
    public Server rsServer()
    {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();

        endpoint.setBus(bus);
        endpoint.setAddress("/");
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(new ArrayList<Object>(controllers));
        endpoint.setExtensionMappings(getExtensionMapping());

        // jsonProvider() is an instance of org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider
        endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(jsonProvider()));

        return endpoint.create();
    }
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@Path("/v1/test")
@Service
public class SimpleTestController extends BaseController
{

    @GET
    @Path("/gettest")
    @Produces(value = { "application/json" })
    @Consumes(value = { "application/json" })
    public Response getTest()
    {
        BlankResource blankResource = new BlankResource();
        blankResource.setTest("WORKING");

        return Response.ok(gson.toJson(blankResource), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/posttest")
    @Produces(value = { "application/json" })
    @Consumes(value = { "application/json" })
    public Response postTest(BlankResource blankResource)
    {
        blankResource.setTest("WORKING");
        return Response.ok(gson.toJson(blankResource), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Note: BaseController is effectively empty, so we can ignore that.

I have also disabled all @Providers to ensure nothing is interfering. Same with spring security.

I have used both Postman and CURL to test this.

GET URL that works:
http://localhost:8080/selector-service/v1/test/gettest

POST URL that does not work:
http://localhost:8080/selector-service/v1/test/posttest

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/selector-service/v1/test/posttest' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=262BEEF808419C6CEC61E064AEA3EEAA' \
--data-raw '{
    "test": true
}'
```

Update(12/31/2020) Another interesting note: When I run a POST on the method, it returns a 404 but when I try to GET the POST endpoint it returns a 405. This stands out to me because it appears that the server has indeed registered the post endpoint.

Update(1/4/2020) I found a [blog post](https://tech.asimio.net/2017/06/12/Implementing-APIs-using-Spring-Boot-CXF-and-Swagger.html) from someone who configured a similar setup using "cxf.jaxrs.component-scan". I followed this guide which rendered my rsServer() @Bean redundant. I have tried removing it. This had no effect and I am still having the same issue.

service.properties:

```
server.address=localhost

cxf.path=/
cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true
```

Comment: I know you said it's empty, but is the BaseController annotated with @RestController?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. No it is not annotated with anything. It is just some constants and for auto wire purposes.

Comment: Additionally, I think that would also break the @GET annotation, but that works when tested.

Comment: Can you please share the service urls for Get an Post.

Comment: @P.Sanjay I updated the question to include this information at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try mapping Spring's DispatcherServlet and CXF Servlet to different paths?

Something like:

```
# Spring MVC dispatcher servlet path. Needs to be different than CXF's to enable/disable Actuator endpoints access (/info, /health, ...)
server.servlet-path: /

# http://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html#SpringBoot-SpringBootCXFJAX-RSStarter
cxf:
  path: /api # CXFServlet URL pattern
  jaxrs:
    component-scan: true
```

Btw, I'm the author of the blog post you are using as a reference:

https://tech.asimio.net/2017/06/12/Implementing-APIs-using-Spring-Boot-CXF-and-Swagger.html

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response. Due to a design requirement, I do need cxf.path=/
I have to admit, I don't know the difference between the 2 path settings. I was not initially setting "server.servlet-path"
I did configure it as mentioned for the sake of testing though. It causes the @POST to return a 403

Comment: [SOLVED] I am adding a note for future individuals with this issue. Separating the two paths did indeed fix this. If you end up with 403s, you probably need to change your spring security settings. Maybe disable csrf.

Answer (score 0):

In JAX-RS your `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers must match what your method declares in the `@Consumes` and `@Produces` along with the URL.  So with Curl you'd have to do:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/selector-service/v1/test/posttest
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have been using postman and it has been set up correctly to be configured as such. The code from postman is added to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @DanielMcBride - add an `Accept` header too.

Comment: I am pretty sure it defaults to Accept */* but I went ahead and tried it. There was no difference. I updated the post.

Comment: You're right @DanielMcBride - I was thinking of a standard JAX-RS environment and this isn't.  I'll keep digging.  For reference, this works fine in a JEE environment.

Comment: Thank you. I included the specific guide I used. I have some deviations, but nothing I can think of that might cause GET to work but not POST. I assume there is something specific to the spring-starter implementation that is causing the issue.